# Does mysql use B-tree,B+tree or both?

Tags: mysql, index, btree

I did some search on the matter and I found out that Mysql uses B+Tree index, but when I run "show index" the index type that I get is Btree. And I found in this [article](http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/all-about-indexes-part-2-mysql-index-structure-and-performance) that Mysql uses both Btree and B+tree. If it is true that it uses both; why is it named Btree without mentioning B+tree, in which case each one is used. I know the difference between the two, and I want to do some queries to figure out the difference in performance between B-tree and B+tree indexes. Which leads to my second question, is there a big difference between the two in performing certain queries, if yes, please give an example.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like a B+ Tree - see [here](https://guptavikas.wordpress.com/2012/12/17/b-tree-index-in-mysql/). The different appears to be that in a B Tree, the last leaf node in a branch doesn't point to the next node by order in the tree - i.e. it doesn't point across the end of the leaves - in a B+ Tree, it does!

Comment: @Vérace I have seen that link before when I was reading about the matter, and it is so confusing to me. The explanation and figure is actually that of B+tree, but ,like mysql, the writer is calling it B-tree. I don't know if it was intentional or if he just made a mistake. I am started to think that it doesn't matter if it is B-tree or B+tree, if people are referring to them by the same name, the difference between them must be of no importance.

Comment: I think it **does** matter. B Trees and B+ Trees are **not** the same thing! A B Tree is simpler than a B+ Tree - with a B Tree, there are no pointers to the next element and the tree has to be traveresed - with a B+ Tree, that process is made a lot easier!

Comment: @Vérace so was it by mistake that he called B-tree in the link you gave?

Comment: I think so. The terminology seems to be a bit ambiguous - no surprise when it comes to MySQL! :-)

Comment: @Vérace Ok I got it, thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 15, accepted):

InnoDB uses B+Tree indexes, not B-Tree. All details about InnoDB data structures can be found [here](https://blog.jcole.us/innodb/). You may also want to look at [these diagrams](https://github.com/jeremycole/innodb_diagrams). The author of both the resources, Jeremy Cole, was head of MySQL team at Google.

Why is the syntax `BTREE` instead of `B+TREE`? This question should be posed to some MySQL or MariaDB engineer, but I see at least two possible reasons:

- B+TREE would be a very bad keyword, because it contains `+`, which is usually an operator.
- That syntax is older than InnoDB. It is probably as old as the `ISAM` storage engine, which exists no more. It is very possible that B-TREE was used at that time.

Why does the documentation state that InnoDB uses B-Tree? Well, not all MySQL users are supposed to know what B+Tree is. This may be an oversimplification, but in that context it seems to me acceptable.

You wrote that you know the difference between B-Tree and B+Tree. Than the different performance characteristics should be clear:

- B+Tree is faster for sorting;
- B-Tree is faster when you insert values in the middle.

But in general, B+Tree is considered superior. How much? I don't know, but surely not orders of magnitude.

Comment: thank you for the explanation, but you didn't comment on what they said in the article(that Mysql uses both ) are they perhaps talking about other engines that might be using B-tree, do you know any that use B-trees. I really need to make a B-tree index and another B+tree to see the difference in speed between the two.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but you didn't comment on the link I gave, it said that Mysql uses both B-tree and B+tree, so does it mean that there are other engines that use B-tree, cause so far the one I looked up use B+tree, unless I got things wrong. And what I meant by difference between the two is; if there are queries that are executed faster when the

Comment: It is possible that MyISAM uses B-Trees, but it would be weird. Other engines don't, imo. But I think I answered about the difference: ORDER BY and GROUP BY take advantage of B+Tree.

Comment: I believe that the article is simply wrong. For sure it is wrong when it says that MEMORY uses both HASH and BTREE: it only supports HASH.

Comment: MyISAM had BTree indexes that were not B+Trees.  In that engine, it was less practical to implement B+Trees, and BTree was quick-and-dirty (but still very useful) -- the general philosophy of MyISAM two decades ago.

Comment: @FedericoRazzoli - I'm pretty sure `MEMORY` used to have only `HASH` indexes; `BTree` (B+Tree??) was added later.

Answer (score 3):

A `B+Tree` is a *just* a binary search tree, like a `B-Tree`, where,

- The leaves (buckets) have links to the right and left siblings buckets), making the tree an index into a [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list). Usually each bucket is sized to be one disk read.
- Data is only stored in the leaf.

A `B-Tree` for reference stores data in the nodes, and leaves, and has no such link because scanning requires backtracking.

The idea of a `B+Tree` is to maximize read-size for disk seeks. It's unlikely that any database that implements a `B+Tree` would use `B-Tree`, unless they're only ever interested in Index Seeks, and not Index Scans. The overhead of the link isn't substantial. Not to mention, in the method of `B+` tree gives rise to any model of concurrency, see the [Lehman and Yao](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs345d-01/rl/blink.pdf).

It's important that all of these differences are mere optimizations on the same idea. For instance, that Lehman and Yao paper above references B- Trees in the abstract and then mistakenly (imho), says "we consider a simple variant of the `B-tree` (actually of the B*-tree, proposed by Wedekind)". That's weird, because I think Wedekind proposed a B+Tree.

These terms are grossly confusing. Check out this [*"The Ubiquitous B-Tree"* published in 1979](http://cs.kangwon.ac.kr/~ysmoon/courses/2005_1/dwnolap/Comer79-U-B-trees.pdf) if you really want a waste a day,

> Perhaps the most misused term term in the B-Tree literature is the B*-Tree.

Comment: Was my comment incorrect?

Comment: @Evan Carroll Thank you for the explanation.